# Drupal 8 database installation is not connecting to docker mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, drupal

Hii i am fairly new to docker , i am using docker to setup my drupal 8 project from existing drupal project , i have tow docker containers one is some-drupal and another one is some-mysql , i linked the some-mysql container to some-drupal container with databse name drupal ,but it is not connecting to database

i have given :

```
database-name : drupal
user:root
pswd:drupal1
advance options:
host:some-sql
port:3036
```

in drupal database installation

this is the command i used to create some-drupal container and link the database container  some-mysql

run -v /Documents/drupalproject --name some-drupal --link some-mysql:mysql -p 8088:80 -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal1 -d drupal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to check if both containers are connected right?

try to access the drupal-container with:

```
docker ps
```

and connect via `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`

after this you can ping your mysql-container via `ping some-mysql` (in fact you wrote one time **some-sql** and the other **some-mysql**)

if you get response then everything should be ok.

Comment: i am getting oci runtime error   exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown when pinging some-mysql

Comment: @vyshnavi I got the **OCI** error because I was trying to do the `exec` within the docker extension for _VSCode_, and found the solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/462, it is an issue with the git bash for windows